# Help - endless dealloc loop

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, dealloc

I am trying to harden my code to avoid low-memory crashes.  I'm stuck on one in particular, which occurs according to these steps:

1. Start app.
2. Tap button that presents modal viewcontroller.
3. Simulate memory warning.

Via NSLog statements everywhere, I see that the initial (presenting) viewcontroller receives a memory warning, then its dealloc method is called over and over until a crash.  For purposes of debugging, I have nothing in my didReceiveMemoryWarning, viewDidUnload, or dealloc methods except the NSLog statements.

What does this sound like?  Maybe I have some retained instance variable which has a pointer back to the view controller?  I just need a general guess of what could be causing this. Can't post my entire view controller code which runs into the 1000's of lines.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, have you looked at the retain count on your view controller when it hit's the dealloc. I would imagine it should be 1. Another thought is do you have a delegate that is retaining the controller and this there is a retain loop between the two?

Comment: Can you try reproducing it with new project and simple view controllers?

Comment: Yeah, I think I found the problem.  I was releasing the viewcontroller in my appdelegate just after I added its view to the main window.  Stupid.  Feel free to answer this question accordingly and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indicated in your latest comment that you think you fixed a case of over-releasing the view controller, but I'm not so sure about that. Over-releasing the view controller will still cause `dealloc` only to be called once.

A much more likely cause of "*dealloc method called over and over until a crash*" is calling `[self dealloc];` in your `dealloc` method, rather than the appropriate `[super dealloc];`. Check that your code is correct in this respect, there may be infinite recursion causing you issues. :)

Comment: This doesn't look to have been the cause but it would make sense as one.  I think it must be something strange, like the view held a retain count on the view controller.  When the view was released (not being visible under the modal controller), it sent a dealloc to the view controller, which probably created some internal error condition.  At this point all code being executed is on a deallocated view controller, or on a modal view controller with no presenter, right?  Anyway, I stopped releasing the view controller in the app delegate and this error no longer occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you overwrite your ViewControllers `release` method? I once did that instead of overwriting `dealloc`. Late night coding FTL.